# In python, can I match part of a file name with special characters between two folders (names) and then copy the found match in the second folder?

Tags: python, copy, special-characters, filenames, matching

A while back I wrote a program to help me sort out files from a common folder where the files are dumped into for me, to different folders based on where the files need to be sent to. I had generous help from users here on StackOverflow and [davetherock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14055259/davetherock) deserves most of the credit for this program. It searches for a specific word in a file name - the recipient - and then sorts the file to the appropriate folder. The recipients do not change and I can add them as needed.

So lately I have to add another file (called A1) from a different folder before I can send the files to their recipients. This other file has to be matched based on the name and surname stated in the name of the original file. These are the names of employees and there are more than a hundred employees. All of these are scans in PDF format. I've been doing it by hand, but I figured I could modify this program to also find this second file and copy it along with the original file.

I'm not making any good progress.

File examples (I randomly generated the names):

Original file that gets dumped into my folder: Džafer Kapetanović - napotitev 13. čl. IKEA, Einrichtungshaus Graz.pdf

Nedim Muratović - napotitev 13. čl. Aldi, Vorarlberg.pdf

A1 file in other folder: Džafer Kapetanović - A1 13. čl. 09.09.2020 - 07.08.2021.pdf

Nedim Muratović - A1 13. čl. 01.01.2020 - 01.01.2021.pdf

So I have to match the Džafer A1 file to his original file before I send it.
Same with Nedim's A1 file.

So, Problem:

1. Have to match  original file with second file based on name and surname, which is written into the file name. Files are in different folders. The A1 files are all in one folder and only get updated upon expiry. The Original files get dumped into one folder.
2. The names feature characters like: č ć š ž đ
3. Incorporate this into the existing program (hopefully).

I've tried to come up with a solution and I've found the [Metaphone](https://pypi.org/project/Metaphone/) algorithm, but I think that's overcomplicating things.

Below is my code. I cut it down to the relevant bits.

Everything that has "A1" in it relates to the new second file.

I feel especially dumb as basically all the filenames are already being handled by the code, I can't figure out how to match the files and how to connect it all together.

Sometimes the way the files are named does not conform to my example, but the name and family name are always first in the file name.

EDIT:
If I convince everyone that dumps the files into the folder to use the " - " sign after the employee name, I can create two lists of names using that. I've put the code below. Now I guess I'd just need a method of comparing the lists and then grabbing the actual files I would need from `A1_files`.

```
import os
import shutil
import pathlib
import pprint
import filecmp
from os.path import join
import re




dir = (#Path to the folder where the originals are dumped)
#added A1_dir to have it stored for later.
A1_dir = (#Path to the A1 folder)


#get the list of files
files = os.listdir(dir)
A1_files = os.listdir(A1_dir)

name_list = []
for filename in A1_files:
    if '-' in filename:
        file_name = filename.split('-')[0]
    else:
        file_name = filename.split('.') [0]
    if file_name not in name_list:
        name_list.append(file_name)

name_list_2 = []
for filename in files:
    if 'Posiljanje' in filename: #this is here because I wanted to see if it works the way I think it does
        print('folder')
    if '-' in filename:
        file_name = filename.split('-')[0]
    else:
        file_name = filename.split('.') [0]
    if file_name not in name_list_2:
        name_list_2.append(file_name)
```

Comment: In general, this is a bit too much code to expect someone to reason through in a stack overflow question. If at all possible I would reduce your question to the specific part/area where you are having issues. It really does help get more/better answers!

Comment: Oh! I just thought I should be as detailed as possible. I'll edit this when I get back home.

Comment: I've updated the post to trim down to the part that I need help with.

Comment: You provide a lot of description, but no examples what exactly do you need to match with what? Give an example of a few files in the original location and the other location and explain what you expect to get matched with what.

Comment: I'm sorry, thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the post with examples.

Comment: I've updated my post with some new code and a possible path to a solution. The code gives a neat list of names, now I just need to figure out if I can compare the two lists and use the matches to get to the actual files and copy them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked this out, but it only works if there is only one file in the folder.

EDIT: Thanks to [Exelian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199682/exelian), this works as I expected it to. Had to replace `all` with `any`.

Here's my code so far:

```
import os
import shutil
import pathlib
import pprint
import filecmp
from os.path import join
import re




dir = (#Path to the folder where the originals are dumped)
#added A1_dir to have it stored for later.
A1_dir = (#Path to the A1 folder)


#get the list of files
files = os.listdir(dir)
A1_files = os.listdir(A1_dir)

#generate first name list
name_list = []
for filename in A1_files:
    if '-' in filename:
        file_name = filename.split('-')[0]
    else:
        file_name = filename.split('.') [0]
    if file_name not in name_list:
        name_list.append(file_name)

#generate second name list
name_list_2 = []
for filename in files:
    
    if '-' in filename:
        file_name = filename.split('-')[0]
    else:
        file_name = filename.split('.') [0]
    if file_name not in name_list_2:
        name_list_2.append(file_name)

#make a list of the names that match
matched_names = [x for x in name_list if x in name_list_2]
#print here for now to see if it works
print(matched_names)

#copy files that have a matching name in their filenames. Currently only works with 1 file in the folder.
for filename in A1_files:
    full_a1_filename = os.path.join(A1_dir, filename)
    if (any(name in filename for name in matched_names)):
        print("Match found:", filename)
        shutil.copy(full_a1_filename, dir)
```