# Matching files based on file name, then copying the found file but it only works if there is only one file in the first folder

Tags: python, file, matching

This is connected to [another post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64875633/in-python-can-i-match-part-of-a-file-name-with-special-characters-between-two-f), but I thought this would make for a more specific question.

I need to match files based on the employee name that appears in the file name. If I manage to convince my co-workers that they stick to a naming convention, I figured I  could write some code to automate the copying. The .pdf files are all scans.

I've found a partial solution to my problem, but the code I write only works if there is only one file in the first folder the code looks into. The employee names have special characters:

č ć š ž đ

For example files in original folder:

Džafer Kapetanović - napotitev 13. čl. IKEA, Einrichtungshaus Graz.pdf

Nedim Muratović - napotitev 13. čl. Aldi, Vorarlberg.pdf

And files that I need to match and copy over (A1 folder):

Džafer Kapetanović - A1 13. čl. 09.09.2020 - 07.08.2021.pdf

Nedim Muratović - A1 13. čl. 01.01.2020 - 01.01.2021.pdf

Code below:

```
import os
import shutil
import pathlib
import pprint
import filecmp
from os.path import join
import re




dir = (#Path to the folder where the originals are dumped)
#added A1_dir to have it stored for later.
A1_dir = (#Path to the A1 folder)


#get the list of files
files = os.listdir(dir)
A1_files = os.listdir(A1_dir)

#generate first name list
name_list = []
for filename in A1_files:
    if '-' in filename:
        file_name = filename.split('-')[0]
    else:
        file_name = filename.split('.') [0]
    if file_name not in name_list:
        name_list.append(file_name)

#generate second name list
name_list_2 = []
for filename in files:
    
    if '-' in filename:
        file_name = filename.split('-')[0]
    else:
        file_name = filename.split('.') [0]
    if file_name not in name_list_2:
        name_list_2.append(file_name)

#make a list of the names that match
matched_names = [x for x in name_list if x in name_list_2]
#print here for now to see if it works
print(matched_names)

#copy files that have a matching name in their filenames. Currently only works with 1 file in the folder.
for filename in A1_files:
    full_a1_filename = os.path.join(A1_dir, filename)
    if (all(name in filename for name in matched_names)):
        print("Match found:", filename)
        shutil.copy(full_a1_filename, dir)
```

Comment: Just a side-note, `dir` is actually a python built-in and it's best practice to not use it as a variable name.

Comment: I see. So I should just define it with my own variable like I did with A1_dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `any` instead of `all` in the last for-loop? But maybe I'm not understanding the question.

```py
for filename in A1_files:
    full_a1_filename = os.path.join(A1_dir, filename)
    if (any(name in filename for name in matched_names)):
        print("Match found:", filename)
        shutil.copy(full_a1_filename, dir)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works as I expect it to work. :) 
I should have experimented with that bit more. It now matches the right files and copies them over. Sweet!